# Merging two dataframes pandas on Id and year where year is missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (dfA and dfB) with a sample from both given below. I want to join the dataframes to produce the Result given

```
dfA
Id, year, B, D
1,  2010, 15, 33
1,  2011, 24, 72
1,  2012, 30, 16

dfB
Id, year, A, C
1,  2009, 100, 1
1,  2010, 75, 7
1,  2012, 60, 3
1, 2013, 42, 4

Result
Id, year, A, B, C, D
1, 2009,100, 0, 1, 0
1, 2010,75,15, 7, 33
1, 2011,0, 24, 0, 72
1, 2012,60, 30, 3, 16
1, 2013,42, 0, 4, 0
```

Attempt

I have experimented with pandas.merge trying inner, outer, left and right joins but am unable to get the desired result!

```
result = pd.merge(dfA,dfB,on=['Id','year'], how = 'outer')
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`merge` has the correct output , we just need to order and `sort_values`

```
s=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Id','year'], how = 'outer').\
      sort_index(level=0,axis=1).sort_values(['Id', 'year']).fillna(0)
s
Out[81]: 
       A     B    C     D   year  Id
3  100.0   0.0  1.0   0.0   2009   1
0   75.0  15.0  7.0  33.0   2010   1
1    0.0  24.0  0.0  72.0   2011   1
2   60.0  30.0  3.0  16.0   2012   1
4   42.0   0.0  4.0   0.0   2013   1
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to merge in this case is [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), with the concatenation on the columns axis :

```
(pd.concat([df1.set_index(['Id','year']),
            df.set_index(['Id','year'])],axis=1)
 .reset_index()
 .fillna(0)
.reindex(columns=['Id','year','A','B','C','D'])
)

    Id  year    A       B   C   D
0   1,  2009,   100,    0   1.0 0.0
1   1,  2010,   75,     15, 7.0 33.0
2   1,  2011,   0       24, 0.0 72.0
3   1,  2012,   60,     30, 3.0 16.0
4   1,  2013,   42,     0   4.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As the `Id` and `year` columns are actually used as index, it could make sense to make them indexes and use a join:

```
dfA.set_index(['Id', 'year']).join(dfB.set_index(['Id', 'year']), how = 'outer'
              ).fillna(0).astype(int)[list('ABCD')].reset_index()
```

gives:

```
   Id  year    A   B  C   D
0   1  2009  100   0  1   0
1   1  2010   75  15  7  33
2   1  2011    0  24  0  72
3   1  2012   60  30  3  16
4   1  2013   42   0  4   0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `fillna` with `downcast='infer'`

And a cheeky way of sorting the columns

```
result = dfA.merge(dfB, 'outer').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
key = lambda x: (x not in {'Id', 'year'}, x)
result[sorted(result, key=key)]

   Id  year    A   B  C   D
0   1  2010   75  15  7  33
1   1  2011    0  24  0  72
2   1  2012   60  30  3  16
3   1  2009  100   0  1   0
4   1  2013   42   0  4   0
```

---

#### `stack` and `append`

I don't like this better but just adding color to the answer landscape

```
dfA.set_index(['Id', 'year']).stack().append(
    dfB.set_index(['Id', 'year']).stack()
).unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()

   Id  year    A   B  C   D
0   1  2009  100   0  1   0
1   1  2010   75  15  7  33
2   1  2011    0  24  0  72
3   1  2012   60  30  3  16
4   1  2013   42   0  4   0
```

Answer (score 1):

`merge` produces "correct results". However, NAs need to filled and converted to int and columns ordered. One way to get the right column order is to use less desirable "hard coding" which I found to work better at times than automatic sorting with say `sort_index(axis=1)` or some other way.

```
desired_col_order = ['id','year','a','b','c','d']
B.merge(A,on=['id','year'], how='outer').sort_values(['id','year'])
 .fillna(0).astype(int)[desired_col_order]
```

produces:

[image]